# How to make CefSharp WinForms control Scroll page to Link

Tags: c#, html, winforms, dom, cefsharp

So here is the scenario, using CefSharp in a WinForms application.
We have two pieces of information a page url and a link url within that page.
We want to load the page - easily done, and have CefSharp show the area of the page where the link is located. That is cefsharp automatically scrolls to the right location on the page where that link is within the DOM.

What is the easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure which version you're using, I was able to solve this using the [latest stable version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/) of CefSharp (47.0.0).

First add a handler to the `FrameLoadEnd` event:

```
browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd;
```

The handler is the following:

```
private void OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs frameLoadEndEventArgs)
{
    if (frameLoadEndEventArgs.Frame.IsMain && frameLoadEndEventArgs.Url == pageUrl)
    {
        frameLoadEndEventArgs.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(
            "(function() { var el = document.querySelector('a[href=\"" + linkUrl +
            "\"]'); if(el) { el.scrollIntoView(); } })();");
    }
}
```

The two constants are:

```
private const string pageUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
private const string linkUrl = "http://stackexchange.com/legal";
```

Whenever we navigate to the site in the `pageUrl`, we invoke a JavaScript function in the loaded document. It selects the first element which has an `href` attribute equal to the `linkUrl` using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). If there is an element like that, then we invoke the [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method on it.

This particular example scrolls the following link into view when you visit stackoverflow.com.

[image: Stack Overflow legal link]

I used the [CefSharp Minimal Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/) as a starting point to build my POC.
I uploaded it [HERE](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwb6Bsfrx94pVkFVV2toNUtNRWc&usp=sharing) for inspection.

Rebuild the project, package restore is enabled, so it should get all the necessary packages. After that you can run it. Enter stackoverflow.com into the address bar, hit Enter, and when it's loaded, the view should scroll down.