# WebBrowser scroll control

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am using cefSharp webBrowser in my project.
I was looking for how to control the scroll points in cefSharp webBrowser.
But i couldn't found some information about cefSharp webBrowser.

WithC# winForm default webBrowser, it controls like

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(100,100);
```

What should I do with my cefSharp webBrowser works same as the code

here is my code

```
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm_WebBrowser_Version_Change
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();

        }
        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("mir.com");
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I will be happy if somebody tell me how to lock cefSharp scroll too.

Comment: Looks like it has to be done in JavaScript.
Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970190/how-to-make-cefsharp-winforms-control-scroll-page-to-link) help you?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but thanks to you. This link is really helping me

Comment: There's a javascript scrollto function that does exactly that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

The CEF Sharp browser does not work the same way as the normal built in Microsoft web-forms browser.

The line of code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(100,100);
```

that you present, won't work on a CEF sharp browser instance because it does not have a "Document" property.

More so, the CEF Sharp browser does not expose any property on any of it's interfaces that allows you to directly drill down into the JavaScript API in the same manner that the Microsoft one does.

Instead, what you need to do is to register a JavaScript function inside the page you are loading that performs the scroll operation you require, then you need to call that function from C# using one of the various JavaScript calling functions that CEF Sharp provides.

Which type of call you use in C# to call the java-script depends entirely on when you want to call it and how, you can find more information in the CEF Sharp wiki about the different methods here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/JavaScript-Binding-API

The CEF Sharp wiki in general is a great place to start reading documentation, it covers just about everything you need to know about using CEF Sharp in a C# application:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki

**Update after writing this answer:**
I've just noticed the link to another Stack Overflow question in the second comment under the question, which pretty much shows one method of what I've summed up above.